# How to debug the app if I don't see error in logcat?

Tags: android, debugging, android-logcat

I have a device with custom skin interface. There is no default Android interface and I have to use some specific intent filters to see my activity in the interface. I don't have root on the device but I do have ADB on. I'm working in Android Studio and I can see my app on attach option

[image]

I'm just starting Java and developing for Android so I make a mistakes in my code. When my app running and there is an error it just close and I don't know what is exact error.

In logcat I don't see anything on error filter, on verbose filter I can see something but it doesn't help:
[image]

If to use emulator I can see logcat, but I need to work on this specific device for some case.

Comment: there is the the video of my actions : http://recordit.co/8i7RTDqT8E

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the second screen with Android Monitor on right top corner You have filters option.

And probably You have "**Show only selected application"**.
Change to **"No Filters"** and You should can see Your logs with crash.

Your app is crashing and filter can't handle logs because Your app is already dead.